Update values in a dictionary based on changes made to another dictionary
I would like to know if there is a way to automatically update the value in a dictionary based on changes made to values in another dictionary.
I have 2 dictionaries as follows:
enum CharacterAttributes: String, Codable  {
    case strength
    case constitution
    case dexterity
    case intelligence
}

enum CharacterStats: String, Codable  {
    case maxHealthPoint
    case maxTacticPoint
    case maxActionPoint
    case movementSpeed
}

var attributes = [CharacterAttributes: Float]()
var stats = [CharacterStats: Float]()

The logics are:
stats[.maxHealthPoint] = attributes[.constitution] *  100
stats[.maxTacticPoint] = (attributes[.dexterity] +  attributes[.intelligence]) * 1.5
stats[.maxActionPoint] = attributes[.constitution] * 10
stats[.movementSpeed] = attributes[.dexterity] + 70

What I want to achieve is that whenever a value is changed from attributes dictionary, the corresponding values in stats get updated automatically.
I know for a normal variable I can use didSet keyword, but how to apply the concept to dictionaries?
Thanks in advance for any help.

So stats should depend on attributes, and not the other way around, right? Can stats be changed directly? Is it allowed to do stats[.maxHealthPoint] = 100 for example?

Yes, stats are depended on attributes, not the other way around. however certain value in stats should be allowed to change directly. such as stats[.movementSpeed] = 100

I seem to have missed something. Why doesn't didSet work as a solution? — Also why exactly are these dictionaries? Wouldn't a struct be simpler?

Okay, if some stats can be set, then when should those stats "synchronise" with the attributes? When would stats[.movementSpeed] go back to attributes[.dexterity] + 70 after you have set it to 100?

Sorry, the correct way to change speed should be like stats[.movementSpeed] += someModifier. That way when atteributes[.dexterity] changes, the stats[.movementSpeed] should always stay in sync. It seems that Sash has provided the answer I need. Thanks anyway.

Are you sure dictionaries are the right way to store this information to begin with? Some structs with didSet observers would make this really easy

Try using the didSet observer after encapsulating your dictionaries within a class:
import Foundation

enum CharacterAttributes: String, Codable {
    case strength
    case constitution
    case dexterity
    case intelligence
}

enum CharacterStats: String, Codable {
    case maxHealthPoint
    case maxTacticPoint
    case maxActionPoint
    case movementSpeed
}

class Character {
    private var _attributes = [CharacterAttributes: Float]() {
        didSet {
            updateStats()
        }
    }
    
    private var _stats = [CharacterStats: Float]()
    
    var attributes: [CharacterAttributes: Float] {
        get { _attributes }
        set {
            _attributes = newValue
            updateStats()
        }
    }
    
    var stats: [CharacterStats: Float] {
        get { _stats }
        set {
            _stats = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(attributes: [CharacterAttributes: Float]) {
        self._attributes = attributes
        updateStats()
    }
    
    private func updateStats() {
        _stats[.maxHealthPoint] = (_attributes[.constitution] ?? 0) * 100
        _stats[.maxTacticPoint] = ((_attributes[.dexterity] ?? 0) + (_attributes[.intelligence] ?? 0)) * 1.5
        _stats[.maxActionPoint] = (_attributes[.constitution] ?? 0) * 10
        if _stats[.movementSpeed] == nil { // Allow manual setting
            _stats[.movementSpeed] = (_attributes[.dexterity] ?? 0) + 70
        }
    }
}

Example Usage:
var character = Character(attributes: [.constitution: 5, .dexterity: 3, .intelligence: 2])
print(character.stats)
character.attributes[.constitution] = 7
character.stats[.movementSpeed] = 100
character.attributes[.dexterity] = 4
print(character.stats)

Output:
[SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxHealthPoint: 500.0, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxTacticPoint: 7.5, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxActionPoint: 50.0, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.movementSpeed: 73.0]
[SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxHealthPoint: 700.0, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxTacticPoint: 9.0, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.maxActionPoint: 70.0, SwiftPlayground.CharacterStats.movementSpeed: 100.0]


This is awesome! It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.
